# Как правильно: на волоске или на волосках?

Tags: окончания

*- Наши жизни подвешены на волоск**е**(**ах**).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше сказать так: ***Наша жизнь висит на волоске.***

Или: ***Сейчас жизнь каждого из нас висит на волоске*** (о конкретной ситуации).

***Висит на волоске*** ― это устойчивое сочетание, именно оно обычно применяется.

― Ну, хотя бы жизнью твоею, ― ответил прокуратор, ― ею клясться самое время, так как **она висит на волоске**, знай это! [М. А. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита, часть 1 (1929-1940)]

Примеры из Нацкорпуса: http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E2%E8%F1%E8%F2%20%ED%E0%20%E2%EE%EB%EE%F1%EA%E5&p=1

Answer (score 1):

"На волосках" уж точно нельзя. Комический эффект получается, не чувствуете? Я бы и "жизнь" здесь поставил в единственном числе, но можно и во множественном оставить.